# Having an issue with NVidia card in my DELL Optiplex 755 (GForce 390) not initializing at boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

Here is the log entry I believe shows the error;

```
Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" 
  (argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-046d_0825_4ED1A7A0-02" 
              card_name="alsa_card.usb-046d_0825_4ED1A7A0-02"  
              namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no  
              ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes  
              avoid_resampling=no  
              card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""
  ):  
initialization failed.
```

Workaround is to open terminal and retype

```
apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

in ssh mode, reboot, and the system boots normally.
Any ideas on how to stabilize the boot up?

Comment: I have a number of 755s here, but cannot even think about providing any help, as the first thing needed is details about your software stack. I don't know what Ubuntu product you're asking about, what release etc.   (the `apt install` tells me it's **not** a Core product, but that doesn't narrow it down much)

Comment: The installed Driver that works most of the time is nvidia driver-390, as the card is a GeForce GT520. Standard Ubuntu 20.04 build. when I run ubuntu-drivers list I receive the following; WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
nvidia-340
nvidia-driver-390, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michael Prinzinger on the nNvidia forum for [this post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-when-strating-display-manager-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia-drivers-geforce-gtx-950m/160485/4) on the thread, [Black Screen when strating display-manager after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04. with nvidia drivers (Geforce GTX 950M)](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/black-screen-when-strating-display-manager-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-with-nvidia-drivers-geforce-gtx-950m/160485).

He found the reason the GUI does not startup all the time. His fix is as follows, but read the full blog if you need the technical detail.

> Thanks to generix I was able to get the Performance Mode (NVIDIA-only)
> working.
>
> The final step was to have no xorg.conf at all and let ubuntu
> prime-select handle all xorg configuration via files it autogenerates
> in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.
>
> After deleting `xorg.conf` (and a lot of additional steps I’ve already
> done up to this point) - NVIDIA drivers are working fine now.
>
> For comparison:
>
> ```
> $ inxi -G
> Graphics:
> Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915
> v: kernel
> Device-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] driver: nvidia v: 455.45.01
> Display: server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting
> unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,nvidia,vesa resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz
> OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 455.45.01
>
> $ xrandr --listproviders
> Providers: number : 2
> Provider 0: id: 0x1b8 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 
> associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
> Provider 1: id: 0x1de cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 3 
> outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
> ```
>
> I hope this helps others also stumbling at this point!